# Rome datetimepicker - How do you set the initial Calendar year

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have a rome Datetimepicker displayed; however am not sure as to how you set the initial Calendar Year that is displayed when the calendar modal opens.

I wish to set the initial calendar year to 40 years in the past (keeping the same Month and Day as today's Date), as it wouldn't be very practical to set it to the current month...

JS DateTimePicker Initialization:

```
rome(dpDateOfBirth, {
    time: false,
    weekStart: 1,
    inputFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY",
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried setting the initialValue like below, which works, however I don't want to display it in the .cshtml page's input tag

```
let defaultDOB = moment().subtract(40, "years").format("DD-MM-YYYY");

rome(dpDateOfBirth, {
    time: false,
    weekStart: 1,
    inputFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    initialValue: defaultDOB
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initialValue` property and give it the date as follow `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`:

```js
rome(inputTwo, { initialValue: '2014-12-08 08:36' });
```

In your case default time is being sent as null probably or wrong format console.log it and check it

Comment: This will display 08/12/2014 as the value of the input tag. I was hoping that there was a way of having this null and being able to manipulate the calendar modal's year upon display?

Comment: I'm happy that there is no time. What I'm wondering is.... is there no way to set the calendar without populating the input?